# How to modify RF field strength meter circuit to attach signal strength meter?

Tags: rf, meter, field-strength

[image: 7.023 MHz RF field strength meter]

*Figure 1. 7.023 MHz RF field strength meter*

[image: Signal strength meter]

*Figure 2. Signal strength meter*

What kind of modifications do I need to make to this RF field strength meter circuit, to attach the signal strength meter?

Answer (score 1):

Place a DVM across voltage doubler output C7 .You should get reasonable readings .

Comment: An excellent suggestion (although an analog voltmeter might be more ergonomic)...I'd upvote if only it answered OP's query.

Answer (score 1):

This combination has a good chance. Some component values are a bit odd (e.g. C1 can be 100 nF, R1 better 4k7), but ok for a test.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flsXJn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>